# How to get Zend Studio to autocomplete for a Zend Framework project?

Tags: zend-framework, autocomplete, zend-studio

After I create a couple folders in the /application folder (such as forms and models) and then start adding classes to those folders, how do I make the code auto completion for these classes available in my various other files such as my IndexController.php?

I'm using Zend Studio 6.1 and ZF 1.8.4.

Answer (score 2):

make sure to set the Zend Framework for the 'PHP Include Path' and use phpdoc style comments to set what the types of the different variables are.

Comment: Poor guy got no points or anything. Well you helped me so there.